# How to select particular option in a select list?

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-classic

I'm trying to select option 2, but first it is selecting 2 then changing to 1.

This is the HTML of the select list:

```
<select id="IDITForm@additionalVehicleDrivers|1@youngestDriverExperienceVO@id">
  <option style="background-color: rgb(252, 218, 175);" value="-1">Select</option>
  <option value="1">0</option>
  <option value="2">1</option>
  <option value="3">2</option>
  <option value="4">3</option>
  <option value="5">4</option>
  <option value="1000000">5</option>
  <option value="1000001">more than 5</option>
</select>
```

This is the Watir code for selecting 2:

```
b.select_list(:id,"IDITForm@additionalVehicleDrivers|1@youngestDriverExperienceVO@id").select "2"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using Watir-Classic's `select` method with a parameter that matches both an option's text as well as another option's value.

If you take a look at the [code for the `Watir::SelectList#select` method](https://github.com/watir/watir-classic/blob/master/lib/watir-classic/input_elements.rb#L45-L55):

```
def select(item)
  matching_options = []
  perform_action do
    matching_options = matching_items_in_select_list(:text, item) +
      matching_items_in_select_list(:label, item) +
      matching_items_in_select_list(:value, item)
    raise NoValueFoundException, "No option with :text, :label or :value of #{item.inspect} in this select element" if matching_options.empty?
    matching_options.each(&:select)
  end
  first_present_option_value matching_options, :text
end
```

You can see that:

1. It gets a list of matching options based on text, label and value and
2. Then for each matching option Watir-Classic selects it.

For your specific example, this means that

1. 2 options match the input "2":

   - `<option value="2">1</option>` matches since its `value` is "2"
   - `<option value="3">2</option>` matches since its `text` is "2"
2. Watir-Classic is selecting each of these options, in this specific order, which is why you see the dropdown switch to "1" and then "2"

Given the way the method is written and how your select list is written, you cannot use the `select` method. While the best choice is to move to Watir (previously Watir-Webdriver), there are workarounds in Watir-Classic.

Remove the ambiguity by specifically selecting an option based on only the `value` attribute:

```
id = "IDITForm@additionalVehicleDrivers|1@youngestDriverExperienceVO@id"
b.select_list(:id, id).select_value "3"
#=> will select <option value="3">2</option>
```

If you want to stick to selecting by text, directly locate/select the option element:

```
id = "IDITForm@additionalVehicleDrivers|1@youngestDriverExperienceVO@id"
b.select_list(:id, id).option(:text, "2").select
#=> will select <option value="3">2</option>
```

Comment: This is the very Interesting thing you have explained.

Comment: Will they ever try to fix this problem in Watir-classic? Or since it's deprecated, they wouldn't even touch it?

Comment: @Gopal, I think it would depend on the demand and reasons for users still using Watir-Classic. I am likely the last person on the Watir team that uses Watir-Classic, so the last one that has any interest in maintaining the project. If you don't mind me asking, what are your reasons for still using Watir-Classic over Watir-Webdriver?

Comment: Yes, I tell you why! I have done totally 6 projects in watir-classic. Not only that, I can attach the browser using WATIR-Classic but you can't do when you use webdriver, Can you? I recently have been moved to Selenium, there you can atleast iterate through the browser and you can get the control of a any opened browser, but that's also not possible in watir-webdriver. These are the few reason I am still want to use classic when I go for internet explorer.

Comment: @Gopal, if you have found a way to attach in Selenium, then you should be able to in Watir-Webdriver. Watir-Webdriver is just a wrapper around Selenium. I recently learned that at least Chrome has some attach-like capabilities, but I haven't had time to explore the limitations and problems. Aside from the attach feature, is there anything that actually stops your existing projects from migration to Watir-Webdriver?

Comment: In Selenium, just like Watir 6+, you can only access windows opened by the driver session. One alternative is to start your browser in an irb session (with either Selenium or Watir 6+) instead of from the Start menu. Any new windows you open from it will be accessible in that irb console. This has the additional advantage of working with any browser, not just IE.

Comment: @Justin Ko, Thanks.

Comment: @JustinKo I said I automated 6 projects. And also I have automated 2 Portal project in WATIR-WEBDRIVER, this keeps on creating the visibility checking issue in many places, I couldn't succeded as I was doing in WATIR-classic. Later clients themselves asked me to automate in IE, I happily moved to classic.  May be there are lot of improvement was done in WATIR 6, So I could try with that. Because there are some of the internal pages which I automated using watir-webdriver fails due to some timing issue while I interacted with elements but it's not happening now as when_present is internal NOW.

Comment: @titusfortner Today is day off for me, as soon as I go office on monday, I will check with that and let you know.

Comment: @titusfortner why does this watir 6 page created by powered by selenium? Even when we use watir-webdriver, it was using selenium, right? what's special in watir 6 which has the name powered by selenium?

Comment: Gopal, partly it is realigning the brand. Also, though, using Watir 5, if you selected IE it wouldn't use selenium. In Watir 6 it does.

Comment: @titusfortner I don't understand 'what do you mean by realigning the brad' now WATIR 5 is the meta gem which choose between classic or driver according to whether you pass parameter to 'Watir::Browser.new'. But WATIR 6 doesn't choose between gems. And also you are passing 'ie' as parameter when you tend to initiate the IE brower, so what's the comparison between there and here? I clearly don't find any meaning for 'powered by selenium', because If that was the case, then watir-webdriver should have been introduced that way, no?

Comment: @Gopal. For instance I've had people tell me they weren't using Watir, they were using Watir WebDriver. When the WebDriver spec is the future of browser automation the "WebDriver" distinction is not useful. The legacy implementation of Watir (Classic) is increasingly irrelevant as few places will test IE-only making the behavior distinctions between browsers more glaring. So no more "Watir WebDriver" and Watir 6+ is All Selenium, All the time. Another frequent misconception is that Watir is a competitor to Selenium. The tagline "Powered by Selenium" is intended to make that more clear.

Comment: @titusfortner Okay, Thank you. It's not competitor to Selenium, yes, But I feel WATIR is far more better compared to Selenium(Using Java). After I have done 6 Projects in WATIR, I have recently moved to Senenium Project where I find coding is complex and syntax are not as easy like WATIR. There are certain systax is not even available. For an instance, `b.table(:id,id).rows.each{|row| puts row.cell[0].text]}` such a table iterating systax is not even available. So I love WATIR, WATIR can't be compared with selenium! But since my company was bought by another company ....(continued in next)

Comment: @titusfortner (....continued from above) Since my company was bought by another company I was forced into selenium because they are doing projects in selenium(Java). What makes WATIR unique mainly because all syntax are very easy and neat in WATIR that makes the people to love writing code in watir.

Comment: @Gopal, you don't have to convince me of how amazing the Watir API is, but some of the differences you're seeing are also just Ruby vs Java. You might take a look at this: https://github.com/lithiumtech/mineraloil-selenium It's an open source Java framework for Selenium created by one of the Watir developers

Comment: @titusfortner I think you got me wrong. I am not trying to convince you. I was explainng the easiness of me while I was using WATIR compared to selenium. Don't get me wrong please.

Answer (score 1):

For Watir, you can use index based options where you need to worry about index only. Such as for:

```
<option value="2">1</option>
```

We can use,

```
browser.select_list(id: 'IDITForm@additionalVehicleDrivers|1@youngestDriverExperienceVO@id').options[2].select
```

As it is the 3rd index of given select_list and it follows zero based index ordering. Similarly for,

```
<option value="3">2</option>
```

We can use

```
browser.select_list(id: 'IDITForm@additionalVehicleDrivers|1@youngestDriverExperienceVO@id').options[3].select
```

As it is the 4th index of given select_list.

Answer (score 0):

`#select` matches the text.
If you want to select by value you need to use `#select_value`:

```
b.select_list(id: "IDITForm@additionalVehicleDrivers|1@youngestDriverExperienceVO@id").select_value "2"
```

Comment: Actually select_value is not the right way to do that because people want to choose by text. We can call the select method upon the option object `b.select_list(:id,given_id).option(:text,"2").select`